# Which programming languages does Google Cloud Debugger support

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-debugger

Which programming languages does [Google Cloud Debugger](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.co.il/2014/06/enabling-developers-to-tame-production-systems-in-the-cloud.html) support other than Java?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: Although your comment is very rudely put, I would delete the question if allowed.

Comment: @matt As a matter of fact this is the kind of comment generated by the system, and cimmanon is using it in large series (as others) to clean up some tags and questions. if you want to discuss about it, feel free to [drop in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), we've got funny animals.

Answer (score 2):

As read on [this blog post](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.nl/2014/03/new-developer-experiences-for-cloud-platform.html)

> We’re starting with Maven-based Java builds, but working to release
>   support for other languages, test frameworks and build systems in the
>   future.

So, simply put: none, it's just Java for now.

I know the blog post is a couple months old but there is no new material to be found on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Debugger only supports Java right now. The build doesn't have to be Maven based though.

Answer (score 1):

Support for other languages, including Python, Node.js, and Go, is coming soon. If you are interested in trying out the debugger on one of these languages, please send me a personal message to be included as an alpha tester.

Comment: We won't really see exotics like Scala will we? only the google approved languages I presume.